# Free Portable Software to tell if my graphics card or on board graphic chips can support more than one monitor

Tags: windows, gratis, portable, hardware

Is there a software that:

1. Portable (no need to install)
2. Free (no need to register)
3. Show me information about my graphics card or on board or integrated graphic chips especially information on whether it can support more than one monitor. (If there are 2 or more graphics output port)
4. support Windows operating system